# Foreach explode trim take last date simple dom parser

Tags: php, arrays, dom, simpledom

I want to take only last date from the third div counting from text div, using foreach below is my code

It only shows the date 01.01.1970 i cant get the date and compare it to today dates
    -------------
Part of the page i want to crawler

```
<div class="courses_list">

                                    <article class="course" data-id="4376" data-datepairs="20150718-20150809" data-terms="8">
                                                    <div class="img">
                            <a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=network-security-pentesting-2"><img src="http://ickosovo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/network-a4-90x60.jpg"></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text">
                            <h3><a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=network-security-pentesting-2">NETWORK SECURITY &amp; PENTESTING</a></h3>
                            <div class="excerpt"><p>In the last decade, wireless networks gained a substantial momentum. One of the most beneficial features of wireless networks is […]</p>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                18 July 2015 

                                                                        -
                                    09 August 2015                                                                      </div>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                    ICT Courses                                 </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                                            <article class="course" data-id="4378" data-datepairs="20150727-20150826" data-terms="38">
                                                    <div class="img">
                            <a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=autocad-autocad-lt-2015-fundamentals-7"><img src="http://ickosovo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/AutoCAD-2015-poster-90x60.png"></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text">
                            <h3><a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=autocad-autocad-lt-2015-fundamentals-7">AUTOCAD / AUTOCAD LT 2015 FUNDAMENTALS</a></h3>
                            <div class="excerpt"><p>The AutoCAD / AutoCAD LT 2015 Fundamentals&nbsp;Training course is designed for new users of AutoCAD and for delegates who would […]</p>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                27 July 2015 

                                                                        -
                                    26 August 2015                                                                      </div>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                    Special Focus                                   </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                                            <article class="course" data-id="4439" data-datepairs="20150727-20150918" data-terms="8">
                                                    <div class="img">
                            <a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=web-design-6"><img src="http://ickosovo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/web-design_poster_july-2015-90x60.png"></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text">
                            <h3><a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=web-design-6">WEB DESIGN</a></h3>
                            <div class="excerpt"><p>Many other training companies claim that creating a website is easy and can be done by anyone. While this may […]</p>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                27 July 2015 

                                                                        -
                                    18 September 2015                                                                       </div>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                    ICT Courses                                 </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                                            <article class="course" data-id="4441" data-datepairs="20150728-20150919" data-terms="8">
                                                    <div class="img">
                            <a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=php5-web-application-3"><img src="http://ickosovo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/php-poster_july-2015-90x60.png"></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text">
                            <h3><a href="http://ickosovo.com/?course=php5-web-application-3">PHP5 Web Application</a></h3>
                            <div class="excerpt"><p>Many other training companies claim that creating a Web application is easy and can be done by anyone. While this […]</p>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                28 July 2015 

                                                                        -
                                    19 September 2015                                                                       </div>

                                <div class="applied date_applied">
                                    ICT Courses                                 </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                                </div>






include('simple_html_dom.php');

            $html1 = file_get_html($page1);
        $today = strtotime("today");
                $events_old     = array();
                $events_today   = array();
                $events_future  = array();
        foreach($html1->find('div.text h3') as $e) {

$link = $e->getElementsByTagName('a',0)->href;
            $date_array = explode("-", trim($e->next_sibling()->getElementsByTagName('applied.date_applied', 0)->plaintext));
            $originalDate = trim($date_array[1]);
            $dt = strtotime($originalDate);

     $c = array('title' => $e->plaintext, 'date' => date('d.m.Y', $dt), 'timestamp' => $dt, 'from' => 'ict', 'link' => $link);

                    if($today == $dt) {
                        array_push($events_today, $c);
                    } elseif($today > $dt) {
                        array_push($events_old, $c);
                    } else {
                        array_push($events_future, $c);
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Alright, so what isn't working? Could you perhaps explain more about what exactly is wrong?

Comment: im not getting the date , its just show the date 01.01.1970

Comment: I posted only the code that i want the date to take beacuse i already took the text and the ahref link, i just want the last date to compare to todays date but the thing is that i get only this 01.01.1970 date

Comment: Please post more of the surrounding HTML. There is no `<h3>` present here, for example.  I see you called `getElementsByTagName()` for `applied`, but that is a _class_ on a `<div>` not the tag. It won't be easy to answer conclusively without more of the HTML for context though.

Comment: I edited it the thing is that i cant get the second date not the first one . so i can compare to today dates and array it on upcoming events for example

Comment: `var date=document.getElementsByClassName('date_applied');console.log(date[0].HTML());`

Comment: I edited it give a look now  @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @bono take a look now,

Comment: @sourRaspberri i get a unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) error

Comment: Turn on error reporting & display errors.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  You should see warnings because you aren't targeting the right elements.  To get the right date node, use something like `echo $e->parent()->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->plaintext;`  Then apply your trim() and explode().

Comment: @sourRaspberri posted javascript code, not PHP.  But if you apply the same idea as `$e->getElementsByClassName('date_applied')`, you'll also more easily get the intended date node.

Comment: $date_array = explode(" -" , trim($e->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->plaintext)); used it but this show only the date 01.01.1970 ,  notice:error trying to get property of non-object , @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: You missed the `parent()` which is needed to traverse upward from `<h3>`. Because the `<h3>` itself has no siblings. Look at my previous comment again.

Comment: i edited the question again take a look of the part of the website i want to crawler the link is good everything only the date , i used parent could not get it to work @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: The HTML you have posted now differs tremendously in structure from your earlier examples in that the date node is actually a child of the sibling of `<h3>`. It would have helped to have the right HTML from the beginning.

Comment: `$date_array = explode("-" , trim($e->next_sibling()->children()[1]->plaintext));`  Inside your `foreach` loop, that will work. I verified that it retrieves both dates, which you must `trim()` then `strtotime()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you very much ,  $date_array = explode('-' , trim($e->next_sibling()->children()[1]->plaintext));
            $originalDate = trim($date_array[1]); worked like charm , i dont know how to give u points im new to stackoverflow answer my question as answer and i click as correct thank you man :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some edits, we found the true relevant structure of the HTML markup needing to be parsed:

```
<h3><a >NETWORK SECURITY &amp; PENTESTING</a></h3>
<div class="excerpt"><p>In the last decade, wireless networks gained a substantial momentum. One of the most beneficial features of wireless networks is […]</p>
    <div class="applied date_applied">
       18 July 2015 
        -
       09 August 2015
    </div>
    <div class="applied date_applied">
        ICT Courses
    </div>
</div>
```

It becomes clearer then that the `applied date_applied` element containing the two dates is a child of the first sibling of `<h3>`. You can then access it with `next_sibling()` together with `children()` and use the array index `[1]` to reference the correct child node.

```
foreach ($html1->find('div.text h3') as $e) {
  // get the two dates as an array
  // The second child node of the first sibling to the <h3>
  $date_array = explode('-' , trim($e->next_sibling()->children()[1]->plaintext)); $originalDate = trim($date_array[1]);

  // Trim and convert them to dates:
  foreach ($date_array as &$d) {
     $d = strtotime(trim($d));
  }
}
```

Check your results (now all converted to timestamps):

```
print_r($date_array);
Array
(
    [0] => 1437195600
    [1] => 1439096400
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1437973200
    [1] => 1440565200
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1437973200
    [1] => 1442552400
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1438059600
    [1] => 1442638800
)
```